# Cannot upload large (>50MB) files to SharePoint 2010 document library

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint-2010, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I'm trying to upload a large file to a document library, but it fails after just a few seconds. The upload single document fails silently, upload multiple just shows a failed message. I've turned up the file size limit on the web application to 500MB, and the IIS request length to the same (from [this blog](http://angler.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/increase-the-sharepoint-2010-upload-file-size-limit/)), and increased the IIS timeout for good measure. Are there any other size caps that I've missed?

**Update** I've tried a few files of various sizes, anything 50MB or over fails, so I assume something somewhere is still set to the webapp default.

**Update 2** Just tried uploading using the following powershell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://{site address}
$folder = $web.GetFolder("Site Documents")
$file = Get-Item "C:\mydoc.txt" // ~ 150MB
$folder.Files.Add("SiteDocuments/mydoc.txt", $file.OpenRead(), $false)
```

and get this exception:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "3" argument(s): "<nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>There is no file with URL 'http://{site address}/SiteDocuments/mydoc.txt' in this Web."
```

which strikes me as odd as of course the file wouldn't exist until it's been uploaded? N.B. while the document library has the name `Site Documents`, it has the URL `SiteDocuments`. Not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you updated the right webapp?  Is the filetype blocked by the server?  Is there adequate space in your content database?  I would check ULS logs after that and see if there is another error since it seems you hit the 3 spots you would need too update.

Comment: Double and triple checked the webapp :) The actual files being uploaded are zips, which SharePoint should allow. Loads of content database space too. I've added some more exception info that I gleaned from trying to upload to the document library using Powershell on the server itself.

Comment: Sounds like its having a problem reading the file.  What is the value of $stream if you put this line right after $file definition: $stream = $file.OpenRead()

Comment: $stream gives me `CanRead:True CanWrite:False CanSeek:True IsAsync:False Length:157286432 Name:C:\mydoc.txt Position:0 Handle:3424 SafeFileHandle:Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle CanTimeout:False ReadTimeout: WriteTimeout:`

Answer (score 0):

for uploading a large file, you can use the PUT method instead of using the other ways to upload a document.
by using a put method you will save the file into content database directly. see the example below

Note: the disadvantage of the code below is you cannot catch the object that is responsible for uploading directly, on other word, you cannot update the additional custom properties of the uploaded document directly.

```
public static bool UploadFileToDocumentLibrary(string sourceFilePath, string targetDocumentLibraryPath)
    {
        //Flag to indicate whether file was uploaded successfuly or not
        bool isUploaded = true;
        try
        {
            // Create a PUT Web request to upload the file.
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(targetDocumentLibraryPath);

            //Set credentials of the current security context
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Method = “PUT”;

            // Create buffer to transfer file
            byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[1024];

            // Write the contents of the local file to the request stream.
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                //Load the content from local file to stream
                using (FileStream fsWorkbook = File.Open(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    //Get the start point
                    int startBuffer = fsWorkbook.Read(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length);
                    for (int i = startBuffer; i > 0; i = fsWorkbook.Read(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length))
                    {
                        stream.Write(fileBuffer, 0, i);
                    }

                }
            }

            // Perform the PUT request
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            //Close response
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Set the flag to indiacte failure in uploading
            isUploaded = false;
        }

        //Return the final upload status
        return isUploaded;
    }
```

and here are an example of calling this method

```
UploadFileToDocumentLibrary(@”C:\test.txt”, @”http://home-vs/Shared Documents/textfile.pdf”);
```